# Get Total Rows binded with Model JQuery Data Table

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable, dapper

how can I get the total rows of the result and also with the datatable search working? Right now, I only got the first page of the result which I already filter out with:

```
OFFSET AND FETCH
```

which it will be binded to the model, and I can get the result of the first page with:

```
MyModel.Count()
```

Here is the code that I am using:

**DataAccess.cs:**

```
public IEnumerable<MemberRepository> RetrieveData(MemberRepository repository)
    {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM [Member] AS m"
                + " WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN [MemberStatus] AS ms WITH (NOLOCK) ON m.[Status] = ms.[StatusIdentity] INNER JOIN [MemberAccount] AS ma WITH (NOLOCK) ON m.[Account] = ma.[AccountIdentity]"
                + " WHERE m.[GroupAccount] = 'Group' ORDER BY m.[Name] ASC OFFSET (0) * 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY";

            return Find<MemberRepository>(query, repository);
    }

private IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(string query, T models)
    {
        using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            return conn.Query<T>(query, models);
        }
    }
```

And I access it like below:

**Retrieve.ashx**

```
public int sEcho { get; set; }
            public string sSearch { get; set; }
            public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
            public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
            public int iTotalRecords { get; set; }
            public int iTotalDisplayRecords { get; set; }
            public IList<string[]> aaData;

            public void SetResponse(int echo, string search, int records, int totalRecords, List<string[]> aaData)
            {
                this.sEcho = echo;
                this.sSearch = search;
                this.recordsTotal = records;
                this.recordsFiltered = records;
                this.iTotalRecords = totalRecords;
                this.iTotalDisplayRecords = totalRecords;
                this.aaData = aaData;
            }

public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   { 
        base.ProcessRequest(context);

        MemberRepository models = new MemberRepository();

        DataAccess access = new DataAccess();

        IEnumerable<MemberRepository> MemberLists = access.RetrieveData(models);

        List<string[]> aaData = repository.Select(r => new[]
            {
                r.Name
            }).ToList();

        SetResponse(echo, string.Empty, models.Count(), models.Count(), aaData);
   }
```

**Retrieve.aspx:**

```
$("#myTable").DataTable({
            bProcessing: true,
            bServerSide: true,
            iDisplayLength: 10,
            sAjaxSource: "../Retrieve.ashx",
            fnServerData: function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: aoData,
                    url: sSource,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        fnCallback(msg);
                    }
                });
            }
```

For the total records, what should I replace it with? Right now I just same it with the total records after cut off for the pagination.

Your answer much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you nee to write separate query like 'select Count(*) from yourtable' to fetch total count

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: Hi, is it possible to do with one query and get total rows without along with the total rows with pagination? If can't then how can I access the total rows without pagination if I do with separate query? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two requests from your application server to the database server, the first is the one you already have and the second should be a query which returns the count of the records corresponding to your filter, but without gathering only the subset to be visualized. The reason is that you should not load all rows into memory, since that could be a huge waste, so you load only a subset. But since you load only a subset, you cannot load the number of all elements from that, since you posess only a subset. So you need a query with columns for the datatable and another query with the count for the count.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but can you please provide an example for your statement? I am confusing on your statement.